# How to change iOS button style on tap with CSS

Tags: html, css, ios

I'm trying to get rid of the default button styling while the button is pressed. Inactive it looks like this:

[image]

On tap it looks like this:

[image]

The border appears slightly after the click and disappears shortly and disappears after a splitsecond. I don't manage to remove the it however. The code looks like this:

HTML:

```html
<button>This is a button</button>
```

CSS:

```css
button:active {
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
}
```

Because the border appears slightly after the tap, it would make sense that it isn't targetable with `button:active`. What would be the right way to remove all feedback on tap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, in case anyone has the same problem:

```css
button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you try adding `!important` like this:

```css
button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button:focus {
  border: none !important;
  background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Doesn't work though. Edit: Tried to clarify my question